# What function describes this problem of every possible breeding of a set of dogs?

Tags: exponential-function, factorial, trees

If I have `n` dogs `[a, b, c, ...]`, and I want to breed them in every possible combination (every possible binary tree made of nodes `[a, b, c, ...]`), how many different end-result puppies are possible? (**edit:** gender doesn't matter, any dog can breed with any dog, so, unrealistic, but more general.)

I can't quite wrap my head around it, but I started thinking there are `n!` possible puppies with exactly the same parents, but bred in a different order.

I get that by taking every permutation of `n` dogs, and each couplet's offspring breeds with the next couplet's offspring, and so on. But that doesn't quite answer it since, given the same starting permutation, I can have many binary trees (ex some deep, some wide). I'm thinking that there are `log2 n` different binary trees for one given permutation. But that doesn't always give whole numbers...

So, the best I've got is `n! * log2(n)`, but that can't be right.

Thoughts?

(PS, not homework, I'm a nerd, and my wife and I are buying a puppy :) )

**edit2:** a note on genetics, obviously, the exact same tree will yield different puppies every single time because of how genes/meiosis/crossover works. I'm really interested in the general case. How many different trees are there, with each parent represented once.

**edit3:** Is the correct answer the Catalan numbers? (IE every possible binary tree given a set of count=n) `(2n)!/(n!(n+1)!)` [oeis.org/A000108](http://oeis.org/A000108) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16004841/3884713?

Comment: You need to know how many males and females there are. If for example there is 1 male then there are n-1 possibilities while for 2 males there are 2.(n-2).

Comment: @TomCollinge: good point, I can't believe I missed *that*. I edited it. To make it more general, what if we considered that any dog can breed with any dog.

Comment: Well I suppose this is the world we live in today !

Comment: You need to think about the restrictions a bit.  It doesn't seem that order should matter-should abcd be different from dcba?  At the first round you probably want to prevent a dog from breeding with itself, so you can't have aa in an odd/even location.  After that it should be ok, as you could have two ab's in the first round, so you could get abab in the second.

Comment: @RossMillikan: good point on ordering, I think that since I want to count the possible end result puppies, surely "flipping" the tree doesn't make a difference, any isomorphic tree will yield the same end puppy (or I guess, the same distribution of puppies). Is my intent unclear in the wording?

Comment: Your use of $n!$ seems to say we should care about order.  Note that a $k^{th}$ generation dog will have $2^k$ parents, which solves your $\log_2$ being non-integral.  I think we have a partition problem if we ignore the first round same parent issue.

Comment: upon further research, is the correct answer this: https://oeis.org/A000108 ?

Comment: I don't think it can be that sequence because it has to depend on two variables-the generation and the number of starting dogs.  That sequence only depends on one.  It seems to me that aabc should be different from abcc because the first has twice as many genes from a

Comment: @RossMillikan: one parent shouldn't be represented twice though, right? If that's not what you meant, could you clarify?

Comment: Yes, I think it can be.  Maybe a and b mate to make ab and a and c mate to make ac in the first round.  Then if these two mate, you get half your genes from a and one quarter from b and c. That would be different from getting half from c and a quarter from a and b.  But that is my reading of the question and there are other reasonable ones.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are concerned about fractions of the parentage that each of the $n$ dogs contribute to a given puppy.  A $k^{\text{th}}$ generation puppy will have $2^k$ ancestors, who may be repeated.  You are looking at [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $2^k$ into $n$ parts-you express $2^k=A+B+C+\dots N$ where the capital letters represent how many of that type of parent there are.  There are ${2^k+n-1 \choose n-1}$ of these.

A subtlety is that you probably don't want the same dog breeding with itself in the first round.  After the first you don't worry, because there could be two ab puppies in the first round to breed together.  This will impose the restriction that no part can be larger than $2^{k-1}$ but all others will be possible.  We can note that only one part can be larger than that, so compute the number of strings that have too many a's and subtract $n$ times that.  The number of compositions that have $i$ a's is just the number of weak compositions of $2^k-i$ into $n-1$ pieces, so ${2^k-i+n-2 \choose n-2}$  We have to sum this from $i=2^{k-1}+1$ to $i=2^k$, so we have 
$${2^k+n-1 \choose n-1}-n\sum_{i=2^{k-1}+1}^n{2^k-i+n-2 \choose n-2}$$

Comment: Your answer's a little beyond me, and I will study it. To make sure our understanding is aligned, if I have [A B C D E], and I breed A+B to make AB, now A and B cannot breed any more, and I'm looking at all trees possible with [AB  C  D  E]. And find all of those. Is that your understanding of the problem?

Comment: So, is this the way you're thinking? `[AAAA BBBB CCCC] -> [AABC, ABBC, ABCC]`, or is that the right way of thinking about it?

Comment: Or parents = `[8A 8B 8C 8D]`, and end-results of `[4A-2B-1C-1D, 4A-1B-2C-1D, 4A-1B-1C-2D, 2A-4B-1C-1D, ...]`

Comment: Once you mentioned thinking in strings, and fractions of parentage, that makes me to think of the above, where each parent's fraction is represented by the count of their corresponding letter. But you mention no parent can have more than `2^(k-1)` genes represented, but shouldn't it simply be that they can't have more than `1/2`?

Comment: As a fraction it can't be more than 1/2, if you have discrete generations. I was working with the number of characters. If your starting population has a number of a's that restriction goes away and it gets easier